# How to change Font Name from TextFrame in adobe illustrator?

Tags: c#, wpf, adobe-illustrator

I'm accessing a ai file from wpf Application and it runs and adds a text just fine

I need to change the font but I coudln't find any intuitive way to do so nor finding resources to help me out

any directions are welcome:

```
Illustrator.Application app = new Illustrator.Application();
//Illustrator.Document doc = app.Documents.Add(Illustrator.AiDocumentColorSpace.aiDocumentCMYKColor, 400, 240);
Illustrator.Document doc=app.Open(@"C:\folder\illu_1.ai");

Illustrator.Layer layer1 = doc.Layers.Add();
layer1.Name = "1";


Illustrator.TextFrame textFrame = layer1.TextFrames.Add();

object[] position = new object[2] { 0, 300 };
textFrame.Position = position;
textFrame.Contents = "Some text";
textFrame.Height = 100;
textFrame.Width = doc.Width;
textFrame.CreateOutline();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to change the font family of your TextFrame.

```
textFrame[FrameNumber].textRange.characterAttributes.textFont.name = app.textFonts.getByName("FontFamilyName");
```